# How to find file location from fileID in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I use `fopen` to generate a fileID:

```
fid = fopen('\some\path\to\toto.dat','r')
```

Is it possible to identify which file has been opened, solely from `fid`? For example,

```
fname = identify(fid);
disp(fname)
>> \some\path\to\toto.dat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can! The code is simply: `fname = fopen(fid)`. You can obtain additional information including permission, machine format, and encoding as well. Documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html